# How long is spin training good for in the USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, spins, cfi

Written tests are only good for 24 calendar months before they must be applied to a certificate (or lost).  Spin training is a requirement of the flight instructor certificate.  Does the required spin training have the same limitation of life as a written test?  Or, is it like an endorsement where it's good "forever"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CFI candidates receive a spin training endorsement with no expiration date. According to [AC 61-65E (the endorsement appendix)](http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65e.pdf), it should look like this:

> #### 46. Spin training: section 61.183(i)(1).
>
> I certify that `(First name, MI, Last name)` has received the required training of section 61.183(i). I have determined that `he/she` is competent in instructional skills for training stall awareness, spin entry, spins, and spin recovery procedures.
>
> - /s/ [date] J. J. Jones 987654321CFI Exp. 12-31-05

The basis for this is that 61.183 doesn't specify a time period in which the endorsement must be received:

> #### [§61.183   Eligibility requirements.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&SID=257acc4699ee7253af775fc7e9492e51&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#14:2.0.1.1.2.8.1.2)
>
> To be eligible for a flight instructor certificate or rating a person must:
>
> > [...]
> >
> > `(i)` Accomplish the following for a flight instructor certificate with an airplane or a glider rating:
> >
> > > `(1)` Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor indicating that the applicant is competent and possesses instructional proficiency in stall awareness, spin entry, spins, and spin recovery procedures after providing the applicant with flight training in those training areas in an airplane or glider, as appropriate, that is certificated for spins; and